# High dimensional behavior of Dirichlet Process-based clustering?

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, high-dimensional, infinite-mixture-model

I have a problem stemming from Dirichlet Process Gaussian Mixture Models (DP-GMMs) in high dimension. I'll write this question so that no knowledge of DP-GMMs is needed.

Let $D$ be the dimensionality of our data. Suppose we sample a number of cluster centroids $\mu_1, ..., \mu_C \in \mathbb{R}^D$ i.i.d. from $\mathcal{N}(0, \rho I_D)$. Then, we choose a random centroid $k$ and generate an observable variable $x_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_k, \sigma I_D)$. The likelihood that the datum $x_n$ belongs to the $k$-th cluster is:

$$p(x_n | c_n = k, \{\mu_{c} \}) = (2 \pi \sigma )^{-D/2} \exp \Big( -\frac{1}{2\sigma} ||x_n - \mu_k||^2 \Big) $$

In a DPMM, the likelihood that the datum $x$ belongs to a new cluster is:

$$p(x_n | c_n = \text{new}, \{\mu_{c} \}) = (2 \pi (\rho + \sigma ))^{-D/2} \exp \Big( -\frac{1}{2(\rho + \sigma)} ||x_n||^2 \Big)$$

My question is: as the dimension of the data increases, what happens (in expectation) to the ratio of the likelihood of a new cluster divided by the likelihood of the nearest cluster?

$$\Big \langle\frac{  p(x_n | c_n = \text{new}, \{\mu_{c} \})  }{p(x_n | c_n = \text{closest}, \{\mu_{c} \}) } \Big \rangle_{x_n, \{ \mu_c \}}
$$

By closest, I mean the cluster with the smallest distance $||x_n - \mu_k||$. The above expectation can equivalently be written:

$$ \Big(\frac{\sigma}{\rho + \sigma}\Big)^{D/2}\Big \langle \exp \Big(\frac{1}{2\sigma} ||x_n - \mu_{closest}||^2 - \frac{1}{2(\rho+\sigma)}||x_n||^2 \Big) \Big \rangle_{x_n, \{ \mu_c \}}
$$

Edit: I'm struggling with the marginal distribution over $x_n$ and the distribution over the cluster means. Does anyone know how to characterize these?